# Light on LAN port constantly powered on

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

I installed Ubunutu 18.04, and everything was ok. Yesterday, suddnely the light on my ETHERNET port got powered on contsantly, and is also on even when restarts. Whenever I connect 1 end of ethernet cable to it, the light turns off.

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Some helpful outputs

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 80:e8:2c:71:07:dd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: dc:f5:05:d0:aa:9b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ce ip=192.168.1.17 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4100000-a410ffff
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db1 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX110] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

```
$ sudo iotop -P

 1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init splash
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
    5 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0-events]
    6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~H-kblockd]
    7 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:1-events]
    8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~s_unbound]
    9 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
   10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
   11 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
   12 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
   13 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/0]
   14 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]
   15 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/1]
   16 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/1]
   17 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
   18 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
   19 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/1:0-events]
   20 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/~H-kblockd]
   21 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [c
```

Comment: Anyone? This light is soo annoying.

Comment: Do you mean that the light is on but there is no cable attached to the port? A bit of Google-fu suggests that you may have a hardware fault unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. When I connect the cable, it turns off.

Comment: My Ethernet is working, so it is not a hardware problem.